# JOptionPane - void type not allowed

Tags: java, swing, joptionpane, void

I'm trying to use JOptionPane but I'm getting the error "void type not allowed" for the text part of JOption pane.I'm wondering what i'm doing wrong and what can I do to fix it?

Thanks

```
private void enterData( )
{
for(Bil bilarna : DatList)
{
 if(DatList != null)
 {
     String inputString = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "please enter in amounts for vehicle" + getRegID());
     double input = Double.ParseDouble(inputString);
    }

  }
}
```

Comment: Where you get error? Show stacktrace please.

Comment: It's parseDouble not ParseDouble.

Comment: Getting the error for "please enter amounts for vehicle"

Comment: Does `getRegID()` return "void"?

Comment: why `String inputString` then next code line to make something strange  `Double.ParseDouble(inputString);`, use int/Integer, double/Double